# Getting Transport error while import git

Tags: git, transport

I have imported git from  this url:
`/home/pragis/NextThermal/.git/`
after give git details i am getting the following error:
[Click here to view error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAsK3.png)

An error occured when trying to contact `git@192.168.1.251:22/home/pragis/NextThermal/.git/`
See the Error Log for more details

possible reasons:

- Incorrect URL
- No network connection(e.g. wrong proxy settings)
- .git is missing at end of reopsitory URL

In Error Log

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@192.168.1.251:/home/pragis/NextThermal/.git/: Connection timed out: connect
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:99)
at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:339)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)

Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@192.168.1.251:/home/pragis/NextThermal/.git/: Connection timed out: connect
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:158)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:262)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:202)
... 4 more
```

Comment: I have upload my query detaily please give me the solution

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I cannot help you, but others will find your question and help.

Comment: Your error is about an ssh url but you seem to say you cloned from a local filesystem folder. Look up the possible url schemes at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone and pick the correct one for your situation.

Comment: Hello @SubhaPriya. Were you able to fix this issue? If yes, can you help me with a solution?